# Straight 6 Vs V6

Tags: engine

In the old days most 6 cylinder engines were straight 6 .Nowdays V6 is more popular .The V6 has more balance issues but its compact form should give a better power to weight ratio .What is best for economy?What is best for reliability ? Is it true that there is a trend back to straight sixes ?

Comment: Straight sixes were dropped so that cars could be more compact, having shorter bonnets or hoods for example.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I realize some of this may be disjointed, but hopefully it answers your questions.

There was two big reasons why the 6-cylinder engine *for the most part* went away:

1. They were relatively inefficient and provided mediocre power. If you wanted efficiency, you put a 4-cyl into the vehicle. If you wanted power, you put a V8 in there.
2. They didn't fit in the engine bay very well. They are longer than either a V6 or even a V8.

There are several reasons why the 6-cylinder is a pretty good engine:

1. As you stated, they are much more balanced than a V6.
2. They are stubborn mules ... if you take care of them, they just keep going. It's really hard to kill them.
3. For their displacement, they produce really good torque down low, which is where most engines live.

The main reason the I6 is a smooth running engine is because it has an even number of cylinders all in the same plane. This allows the engine to be designed to have one piston traveling up while another is traveling down. This counteracts the inertia of one with the other and thus is rather smooth. Most V6's were just V8's with two cylinders lopped off. This brought about unevenness because you now only have three pistons in line per side. V8's are mostly 90° V's as well. To make a V6 smoother, it has to have a 120° or 60° spread. This meant that the V6 had to be a completely different motor than the V8 or you had to compromise with various amounts of weight slinging around on it if you kept it to the 90° V.

I read through three different articles ([this one](https://www.autonews.com/article/20171024/BLOG06/171029886/return-of-the-inline-six-why-the-classic-engine-layout-is-making-a-comeback), [this one](https://www.roadandtrack.com/new-cars/videos/a8645/the-enginerdy-dept-straight-six-revival/), & [this one](https://www.hagerty.com/articles-videos/articles/2019/04/19/why-inline-6-is-making-a-comeback)), which all say the same basic thing: yes, I6's are making a comeback.

During the days of carburetion, one of the inherent issues with the I6 was that the outside cylinders ran lean. In order to try and compensate for this, the inside cylinders (those closest to the carb) would be made to run rich. There was really no happy medium, and therefore you saw inefficiencies. Today, with fuel injection run on everything, the injectors provide the right amount of fuel for each cylinder, which allows them to run more efficiently.

In the newer engines, most of the I6's are mainly modular, meaning several different engine utilize the same internal parts, which makes manufacturing them a lot cheaper. You only have to engineer a single type of engine and you have all kinds of parts to utilize throughout the different types.

With turbocharging and supercharging so high on everybody's list, these two forms of forced air induction are helping with the resurgence of the I6. These allow the I6 to make stupendous power in relation to their size. It's harder to turbocharge a V6 because there's basically no room to do that ... the spread of the engine takes up the engine bay. That makes it hard to place a turbo *easily*, while still allowing the other parts under the hood to not get completely baked. With the I6, there's plenty of room either side of the engine to fit one in.

In the Hagerty article, they state that MB and JLR are using a 48-volt system in their new cars which allows them to run electric superchargers on their new I6 engines. Both MB and JLR had gotten rid of their I6's around the turn of the century, but then in the last few years have picked them back up again.

Another reason the I6 fell out of favor is because in a front end crash, they aren't as safe. They tend to get pushed back into the passenger compartment a lot easier than a I4 or V8 would. Auto manufactures have figure out new ways of overcoming that, as well.

Comment: To avoid lean mixtures for 1&6, the engines were sometimes given 3 dual-barrel carbs...

Comment: @SolarMike - Not on many production vehicles I've seen (or heard of). The 3x2 setup would have to flow all the time, with basically one "barrel" providing fuel for its own cylinder. I can see where this would be problematic in the tuning arena, just like with multi-carb'd motorcycles ... takes a special hand.  But, yah, it would definitely help the lean issues with 1&6, no doubt.

Comment: The Lotus Sunbeam was a 2.2 litre 4 cylinder with 2 two barrel dcoe weber carbs - needed a 4 pipe manometer to tune that and, as you say, a special hand. Once right though, boy did it fly...

Comment: @SolarMike - Yah, I can imagine! I've never driven a Sunbeam, but it's on my list ;-) Sounds like a fun little car!

Comment: they did very well for a couple of years in the RAC rallies, but the Audi Quattro appeared and swept the board of everybody... and that was a brutal car - really had to be awake...